# Issue w/ Programmatic Zoom v4

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using `d3.js v4`. I'm currently implementing programmatic zoom. This [Panning and Zooming Tutorial](http://emptypipes.org/2016/07/03/d3-panning-and-zooming/) has helped tremendously. My zoom works with scrolling wheel, but I want to create buttons to zoom. I know what necessary for zooming and panning is a translation `[tx, ty]` and a scale factor `k`. I'm using timescale for my x-Axis. I've managed to get `tx` and scale factor of `k`, by getting the pixel value of `p1 (point 1)` and `p2(point 2)` on the x-axis and then using those values to get a k (Scale factor). Like such:

```
var k = 500 / (xScale(p2) - xScale(p1)); //500 is desired pixel diff. between p1 and p2, and xScale is my d3.scaleTime() accessor function.
// for this zoom i just want the first value and last value to be at scale difference of the entire width.
```

Then I calculate tx by this:

```
var tx = 0 - k * p1;
```

Then feeding it into a `d3.zoomIdentity()` and rescaling my xdomain. I created a button to zoom back out. The issue is when I zoom in and then try to use the button to zoom out, it zooms out, but shrinks the x-axis. I can't seem to findout why its shrinking the x-axis instead of zooming back out correctly.

**My JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/codekhalifah/Lmdfrho7/2/

**What I've Tried**

- Read zoom [Documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#zooming-d3-zoom)
- Read through chapter on zoom in [D3.js in action](https://www.manning.com/books/d3-js-in-action)

**My Code**

After wheel zoom is applied I run this function:

```
 function zoomed() {
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush  
var t = d3.event.transform;
console.log(t);
console.log(xScale.domain());
xScale.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
usageAreaPath.attr("d", area);
usageLinePath.attr('d',line);
weatherAreaPath.attr('d',weatherChart.area);
focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
focus.selectAll('.circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(getDate(d)); })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d.kWh); })
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 80 + ")");

        ... other non related items
    }
```

The zoom works properly, but after zooming in and then manually attempting to zoom back normal position I want.
My manual zoom button function

```
function programmaticZoom(){
 var currDataSet = usageLinePath.data()[0], //current data set
        currDataSetLength = currDataSet.length,//current data set length
        x1 = currDataSet[0].usageTime, //getting first data item
        x2 = currDataSet[currDataSetLength-1].usageTime, //2nd data item
        x1px = xScale(moment(x1)), //Get current point 1
        x2px = xScale(moment(x2)); // Get current point 2

        // calculate scale factor
        var k = width / (x2px - x1px); // get scale factor
        var tx = 0 - k * x1px; // get tx
        var t = d3.zoomIdentity.translate(tx).scale(k); //create zoom identity

        xScale.domain(t.rescaleX(window.x2).domain());
        usageAreaPath.attr("d", area);
        usageLinePath.attr('d',line);
        weatherAreaPath.attr('d',weatherChart.area);
        focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
        focus.selectAll('.circle')
            .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(getDate(d)); })
            .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d.kWh); })
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 80 + ")");

}
```

Comment: just to be clear; you want your zoom button to always just zoom back to the default initial view?

Comment: @Hamms Well i want to actually be able to zoom into different levels. This was just my first test level. But on the Timescale I would like to zoom from months view, to week view, to one day, to hour, to 15min. My first test level was just to go back to seeing months.

Comment: @Hamms any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking at this for a little while now, and I got it *sort* of working, there's one thing I can't figure out but you might be able to since you seem more familiar with d3 than I am. In your `programmaticZoom()` function, I noticed that `tx` is the offset for where the start of the graph is, and `k` is the scale. Using this, I changed the block:

`var k = width / (x2px - x1px); // get scale 
 var tx = 0 - k * x1px; // get tx
 var t = d3.zoomIdentity.translate(tx).scale(k);`

to

`var k = 1; 
 var t = d3.zoomIdentity.scale(k);`

First, when `k = 1.0`, the graph will fit in the window perfectly. The reason I believe setting `k` to its former value was wrong is that, when you increase the value of `k` so that `k > 1.0`, it stretches the width of the graph past the screen. The content on the graph has to be readjusted so that it can take up as much space *on the graph* as possible, while still being within the bounds of the screen. With `k < 1`, which is what happens with `width / (x2px - x1px);`, the graph shrinks to be less than the size of the screen. Readjusting like this will only make the graph's content fit to take up the maximum that it can *within the graph*, but since the graph is smaller than the screen, it will be readjusted to fit the shrunken graph and appear smaller than the screen.

I got rid of `tx` entirely because it offsets where the graph starts at. When the graph is zoomed in, it's width is stretched past the screen. It makes sense to offset here because you need to have your offset equal to where you want to begin viewing the graph, and allow the parts you don't need to remain off of the screen. In the case where you're zooming out all the way, the graph *is* the size of the screen, so offsetting is going to cause your graph to not start at the beginning of the screen and instead push part of it off of the screen. In your case, with `k` already shrinking the graph, the offset causes the shrunken graph to appear in the middle of the screen. However if the graph was not shrunken, the offset would push part of the graph off of the screen.

By changing that, the zoom out button *appears* to work, however there is still a problem. In the `zoomed()` function, you set `var t = d3.event.transform;`. The `d3.event.transform` contains values of `k, x, and y` that need to be `1, 0, and 0` respectively when completely zoomed out. I cannot change these values in the `programmaticZoom()` function though, because `d3.event.transform` only exists after an event was fired, specifically the mouse wheel. If you are able to get these values to be `k = 1, x = 0, y = 0` only when the zoom button is clicked, the issue should be completely fixed.

Hopefully that helped some, I'm not very familiar with d3 but this should solve most of your problem and hopefully give you an idea of what was going wrong.